# Xamarin forms Multilingual not picking other language key

Tags: xamarin.forms, multilingual

I am trying Xamarin forms a Multilanguage demo.  In this, I tried both the options 
1) plugin. Multilanguage package 
2) static resource(without plugin).
I just downloaded the demo from the following site 
1) https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultilingualPlugin
2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows

But both the demo not picking another language key. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please see this link's end:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows#test-localization ,Testing localization is best accomplished by changing your device language.`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` in code but behavior is inconsistent across platforms so this is not recommended for testing. And I test `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` it not work in my emulator.

Comment: Hi thanks @LeonLu-MSFT I downloaded the sample code directly from the Microsoft site and tried to run and also as mentioned I run the plugin, Multilanguage package code as well but in both the case it is not picking other than default resx file which is English. I tried to assign culture explicitly multiple time but no luck and the other thing is  no error coming.

Comment: I do not use `Multilanguage` plugin. I download this demo:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/usingresxlocalization/ , If I change the deivce language in Android Settings, it worked.

Comment: Thanks I tried the same but no luck I am using vs2019

Comment: The problem was solved?

Answer (score 2):

This is an error after Visual Studio update (Version 8.6 (build 4520)). There is a workaround to use the Last stable version of Android SDK.

In Android.csproj, at the last line (inner the tag project) add the follow lines:

> 

```
<Target Name="_ResolveSatellitePaths" DependsOnTargets="_ResolveAssemblies">
    <ResolveAssemblyReference AllowedAssemblyExtensions="$(AllowedReferenceAssemblyFileExtensions)" AssemblyFiles="@(ResolvedUserAssemblies)" AutoUnify="$(AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences)" FindDependencies="True" FindRelatedFiles="False" FindSatellites="True" SearchPaths="$(AssemblySearchPaths)" TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)" TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName="$(TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName)" TargetFrameworkDirectories="$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)">
      <Output TaskParameter="SatelliteFiles" ItemName="_AndroidResolvedSatellitePaths" />
    </ResolveAssemblyReference>
  </Target>
```

EDIT:

there is already a VS update that solves this problem.